# How to rename the html title from Grails g:link with target _blank

Tags: html, grails, grails-2.0

I am working with Grails. I have a link in a gsp page which is opening a new tab by the target `_blank`. In that tab I am generating a pdf report using Jasper plugin.

Is there any option to give a name of the new opened tab? In my case the title of the html page is giving my function name from controller.

Here is my link:

```
<g:link target="_blank" action="printDoReport" params="[slsDoMstMid: doForIssueInstance.MID]">Chalan from DO</g:link>
```

Comment: Please include the controller method that produces this page (the one in the new window). Its probably just sending the PDF with content-type "application/pdf", in which case you can't set a title.

Comment: yes it is generating the pdf. So isn't there anything to do it.

Comment: No, not that I know of. You might be able to wrap the PDF in a simple HTML page with an iframe- you could then give the html page a title ???